# Entity Framework composite key definition with column ordinal <> primary key ordinal

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key, code-first

Given a table as

```
CREATE TABLE pk_ordinal_test
(
 C1 INT NOT NULL,
 C2 INT NOT NULL,
 C3 INT NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE pk_ordinal_test ADD PRIMARY KEY (C3, C1);
```

Notice that the primary key has been defined as C3, C1, and the column order is C1, C3.

Should the Entity Framework code-first configuration for the primary key be in **primary key ordinal**:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.C3, x.C1 });
```

or should it be in **column ordinal**:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.C1, x.C3 });
```

Using EF Tools v6.1.3 from an MSI install, Using Visual Studio -> Add -> New item -> ADO.Net Entity Data Model. Selecting Code-first, generated the following:

```
public partial class pk_ordinal_test
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int C1 { get; set; }

    public int C2 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int C3 { get; set; }
}
```

The primary column order defined above is incorrect.

Comment: Can you edit/add the schema and EF's code first generation to your post from my post on your extension to show what VS is providing?

Comment: You should show that in your answer. I've kept the above question as succinct as possible and to the point.

Comment: I edited my reply and added the schema and EF code first generated code.

Comment: It looks like no info about primary key ordinals are queried by EF 6, as far as I can seee http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/Resources/System/Data/SqlClient/System.Data.Resources.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.StoreSchemaDefinition.ssdl

Comment: I have added a bug here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have entities with composite foreign keys then you must specify the same column ordering that you used for the corresponding primary key properties, so the option you must select is primary key ordinal:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.C3, x.C1 });
```

Comment: That's what I think it should be too. However the Microsoft generator spits it out in column order (C1, C3) which I think is a bug.

Comment: That's weird, could you show your `ordinal_test` entity? Are you configuring everything using Fluent Api, or are you also using some Data Annotations?

Comment: I am going off what Neil is saying: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Discussions (p.s. I am the author of the entity framework reverse poco generator). My generator spits it out in primary key ordinal, which I still maintain is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't care about the order in the database. It always refers to columns by name, not ordinal. The thing that does matter is [what octavioccl mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32564269/475031)--the order needs to be consistent across your EF model. If a primary key is specified one way, foreign keys that refer to that primary key must be in the same order.

I wrote the Code-first generator. There was a "bug" in the component that extracts information from the database. Like you found, it strips out column order in composite keys. It does, however, preserve which column in a foreign key map to which column in the primary key. So, even though it may not reflect what the layout is in the database, **the generated model will work correctly** with your database.

Comment: Allowing EF to perform a "drop and create" (say for unit testing) it would create the primary key by column ordinal, which is not how it was originally created by SQL.

Comment: @SimonHughes You would also lose views, indexes, triggers, functions, sprocs, synonyms, etc. Again, if you only access it with EF, the key column order just becomes an "implementation detail" that won't actually matter.

Comment: For those coming from EDMX it would need to align with the VS code first generator (column order) which I was told to use for key ordering in EDMX as column order. If people used Simon's generator and stayed with it, it should/would work I believe from what is said above. But I believe it's important to align the two as if I didn't have sprocs I would use the VS system instead so I'd have a conflict between the two generators.

Comment: (happy to know that I guessed at the correct person (Brice) for you to ask. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a code first model from database in Visual Studio 2015 it will assign an Order attribute for the keys in the order of the columns in the schema.  Therefore if you perform a LINQ query such as Find you need to order the primary keys in "column order" as the keys are ordered by the schema column order.

If you were to use a Database First approach with EDMX the guidance is to also use the primary key order per the column order in the designer.  Therefore if C1 comes before C3 and are both primary keys the find method would be used as Find (C1, C3).

Therefore there are two items of evidence, to me that when specifying primary key order with a composite key you are to use the column order when a model is generated in code or designer as the code generator will use the column order to order the keys.

The OP's example (which was generated as a result of my inquiry in a VS extension) is a bit different in that the schema is generating the primary key ordering.  So let's step back and look at this from "hey, I'm going to generate a code first model from your schema.  I see C1 and C3 are primary keys.  When I generate the code first model from your schema I'm going to iterate columns in order AND assign an Order attribute for the primary key columns."  This results in a usage pattern based on column order directly.

So again, the OP is generating a model from a schema, EF generates the order in code per schema/column order.

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserSetting](
    [userId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [deleted] [BIT] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserSetting_deleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [key] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [lastUpdatedUtc] [DATETIME2](7) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserSetting_lastUpdatedUtc]  DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [notificationMessage] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [notificationType] [INT] NULL,
    [stringValue] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [synced] [BIT] NULL,
    [userSettingId] [NCHAR](36) NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [DATETIME2](7) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserSetting_timestamp]  DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [modelVersion] [INT] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserSetting_modelVersion]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [preview] [BIT] NULL,
    [createdUtc] [DATETIME2](7) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserSetting_createdUtc]  DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserSetting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [userSettingId] ASC,
    [userId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is what is generated in the Visual Studio Code First from Database:

```sql
[Table("UserSetting")]
    public partial class UserSetting
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int userId { get; set; }

        public bool? deleted { get; set; }

        public string key { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? lastUpdatedUtc { get; set; }

        public string notificationMessage { get; set; }

        public int? notificationType { get; set; }

        public string stringValue { get; set; }

        public bool? synced { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(36)]
        public string userSettingId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? timestamp { get; set; }

        public int? modelVersion { get; set; }

        public bool? preview { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? createdUtc { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you were to allow EF to drop and create the database, you would want the same primary key ordinal as was originally defined in SQL. 
Hence the correct use of: HasKey(x => new { x.C3, x.C1 });

Comment: @SimonHughes I completely understand your point and it is odd that if the primary keys are ordered that way in the schema why wouldn't we be using a Find in that same order but the EF generation and EDMX usage are counter which may as you suggest be a bug in EF.  Coming from an EDMX using your extension causes me to have to change all of that code to reverse the keys so I need to get to the bottom of this and thank you for your help.  I do see your point, just don't know why EF isn't honoring it. We obviously have a huge issue in conflict from people generating code first in differing systems.